# Rinex formatting in Python. Looping problems

Tags: python, loops, gps

I'm a Python novice and I have an issue trying to format RINEX (satellite navigation data, like GPS), so that I end up with an ASCII file with three columns (GPS time; satellite ID; signal types (several sub-columns)), that ultimately would be manipulated to yield signal delay errors.
I'm currently trying to progress through my code by checking the output at various stages of the script, therefore there's an abundance of print statements scattered everywhere. The main body of my code is:

```
def remove_header(self):
        #Grab header and discard
        for count, self.line in enumerate(self.rinexFile, 1):
            if "END OF HEADER" in self.line:
                self.header_number = count
                eoh = self.line
                self.end_header = eoh.strip()
                print "%s at line %d." % (self.end_header, count)
                self.container_1 = self.rinexFile[self.header_number:]
                open('FALK1179.14o', 'w').writelines(self.container_1)


def epoch_grabber(self):
        #Grab data
    self.rinexFile_one = open('FALK1179.14o', 'r+').readlines()
    for count, self.line_1 in enumerate(self.rinexFile_one, 0):
        #Grab epoch
        #self.raw_data = line.split()
        if " 14 " in self.line_1:
            self.epoch_data = self.line_1.split()
            self.index = datetime.strptime(' '.join(self.epoch_data[0:6]), '%y %m %d %H %M %S.%f0')
        else:
            pass


def satellite_number_and_id(self):
     #Identify number of satellites in each epoch block
     satNum_init = self.epoch_data[7]
     satNum_temp = satNum_init[0:2]
     if satNum_temp.find("G") == 1:
         self.satNum = satNum_temp.replace("G", "")
         self.satNum = int(self.satNum)
     else:
         self.satNum = satNum_temp
         self.satNum = int(self.satNum)

     #List the SVIDs of each satellite
     satNum_init_tem = satNum_init[2:]
     satId_temp = satNum_init_tem.split("G")
     self.sat_Id = filter(None, satId_temp)

def satData_package(self):
    #Looping through for every satellite and create dummy frame
    data = {}
    for line in self.container_1:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue

        if line.startswith(" 14 "):
            if line not in data: data[line] = []
            epoch_line = line
            continue

        self.satData = data[epoch_line].append(line)
        print "satData: %s" % (self.satData)
```

The encountering an issue with the looping, as seen in the epoch_grabber function. My print statements yield the same end epoch, over and over, instead of beginning at the first epoch, say: Epoch: 2014-04-27 00:00:30, Epoch: 2014-04-27 00:01:00, Epoch: 2014-04-27 00:01:30, and so on. Instead it just loops: Epoch: 2014-04-27 23:59:30, Epoch: 2014-04-27 23:59:30, Epoch: 2014-04-27 23:59:30.

The intention is to have the epoch, then all subsequent satellites' signals packed together, then the next "block" where the next epoch begins. Each epoch has an interval of 30seconds. Then the block should be split further to yield individual satellite files, that each contain the epoch in one column, and signals in the remainder.

Any advice welcome

Comment: `self.satData = data[epoch_line].append(line)` looks suspicious to me. As-is, it makes `self.satData` equal to None, because that's what `append` returns. Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: Hello, actually, the satData_package should be commented out. Sorry. It's just drafted and is the next step. Although I'll take your comment on board. Thx.

Comment: Ok, discounting the final function, I don't see anything obviously wrong. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very useful, if you can manage one.

Comment: What would help with the MCVE. You need a RINEX file for that, in particualr the falk1179.14o

Comment: A little bit more info, the code only reads the last epoch: '
Epoch: 2014-04-27 23:59:30
SVs: ['32', '07', '20', '06', '13', '01', '23', '04', '31', '10']
satNum: 10
zeile         42.0004         38.0004'

Comment: I can't see a print statement in the epoch_grabber function to understand where in the code you are referring to. Why not post very simple code that exhibits the problem, and some representative sample data - two line would suffice - and show the output that code+data produces. Quite often the process of reproducing a problem by collecting just the relevant bits together will actually help you solve the problem.